# Add bins of data in a new column based on continous data in existing dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column in R dataframes that derives its values from existing column, which is a continuous variable.

For eg, student$marks which can contain data from 0 - 100. If marks > 90, I have "grade" column which should give it A, between 80 and 90 - B etc. I want to group data in the above way for every range of 10 points. If the score is between 30 and 40, it gets a G. How can I achieve this.

Comment: You may want to have a look of `cut()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `?cut` function.  You can specify the numeric input vector, identify the break points, and assign labels to the groups.  The `right` argument tells the `cut` function to specify whether the interval is inclusive on the left vs right.  Example:

```
set.seed(1)
student = data.frame(marks=runif(20,0,100)) #random grades
student$grade = cut(student$marks, breaks=seq(0,100,10), labels=LETTERS[10:1], right=F)
head(student)
     marks grade
1 26.55087     H
2 37.21239     G
3 57.28534     E
4 90.82078     A
5 20.16819     H
6 89.83897     B
```

Although, if you actually want >90, I think you would need a slightly messier version:
`student$grade = cut(student$marks, breaks=c(seq(0, 90, 10), Inf), labels=LETTERS[10:1], right=F)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `cut` function

```
student$grade <- cut(student$marks, seq(30, 100, 10), 
                     labels = rev(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")))
```

Or we can use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

student <- student %>%
  mutate(grade = case_when(
    marks > 90 ~ "A",
    marks > 80 ~ "B",
    marks > 70 ~ "C",
    marks > 60 ~ "D",
    marks > 50 ~ "E",
    marks > 40 ~ "F",
    marks > 30 ~ "G"
  ))
```

**Example Data**

```
student <- data.frame(marks = c(100, 85, 32, 77, 64, 50, 44, 93))
```